# Mq translate plugin custom post type issue

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I am using a  http://sitemile.com/products/wordpress-pricerr-theme/ theme.

I use mqtranslate plugin to translate my site in two language english and chinese.

Mqtranslate allows the admin to create categories and posts in mulilanguages in the backstore.
It also allows the admin to write the job in mulilanguages. But it gives no access to writing the job categories in mulilanguages. I need this feature coz the job categories are shown in the homepage - i need them switchable between language with the site. I believe it is a easy fix.

Job is a custom post type, there is a problem with custom post type category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQtranslate is a fork of Qtranslate so the hooks should be the same, and to get Qtranslate to Work in custom taxonomies I use this:

```
/**
 * qtranslate custom taxonomies
 */
function qtranslate_edit_custom_taxonomies(){
  $args=array(
    'public' => true ,
    '_builtin' => false
  );
  $output = 'object'; // or objects
  $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

  $taxonomies = get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator);

  if  ($taxonomies) {
    foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
      add_action( $taxonomy->name.'_add_form', 'qtrans_modifyTermFormFor');
      add_action( $taxonomy->name.'_edit_form', 'qtrans_modifyTermFormFor');
    }
  }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'qtranslate_edit_custom_taxonomies');
```

this should work for you as well.

Comment: Thanks for fast respond.you are really doing great for community